# I want to make UI that I can move text around in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-custom-view

I want to make an app that generates card news in android.
Additionally, I want to make UIs that I can move texts around on a photo,
so that I can set the text wherever I want on the photo.

How can I achieve that?

Is there any library that I can use?
or what should I search?

I am currently working on Canvas now.

Thanks!

Comment: *I am currently working on Canvas*  Well, good luck with that . Thx

Comment: nice work mate!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my solution.

I searched with the keyword 'sticker' and I found this site.

[https://blog.uptech.team/how-to-create-snapchat-like-stickers-for-android-50512957c351](https://github.com/uptechteam/MotionViews-Android)

this is the github source
[enter link description here](https://github.com/uptechteam/MotionViews-Android)